# How to get the caller from an event handler as an object in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am really new to Kotlin and since I'm not used with the terminology I haven't found anywhere how can I get an object from an event caller.

For example, instead of writing "addToStack(b1)" I want to write something like addToStack(general term to get the same result):

```
b1.setOnClickListener{
    addToStack(b1)
}
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either write

```
b1.setOnClickListener {
    addToStack(it)
}
```

or

```
b1.setOnClickListener { iAmB1ButWithACustomName ->
    addToStack(iAmB1ButWithACustomName)
}
```

Comment: @Misterhup You can have a look at the kotlin refernece for lambdas.
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter